# create heatmap for each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Below is a df called "compmatrix":

```
             -3.0        -5.0       -7.0    
Gain/DD*DD%  0.009000    0.034000   0.088000    
Gain/Expsr%  0.487000    0.927000   1.628000    
Gain/MaxDD   0.015000    0.021000   0.025000    
MaxDD*iBeta  32.633      193.536    856.520
```

I'd like to apply a heatmap to each row (vs. the whole dataframe), because of the big difference in values.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(compmatrix,cmap='RdYlGn_r',annot=True)
```

but the fact that there's no axis=1 has thrown me off. Can't seem to find the solution I'm looking for in the documentation.

Comment: it's still taking the whole df

Comment: Oh, you want it for each row separately? Got it.

Comment: Ya , as in vmin and vmax for each row (vs. whole df)

Answer (score 5):

Found a handy solution to the problem (and no need for seaborn):

```
compmatrix.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',axis=1)
```